# How to map URLs to my new domain

Tags: .htaccess, jsp

I have currently a Java web app running on Google App Engine with the following url `http://MYAPP.appspot.com`

I recently purchased a domain `example.com` through NAMECHEAP.

How can I make URLs to `http://MYAPP.appspot.com` mapped to `http://www.example.com`?

For example, URL to "www.example.com/admin/index.jsp" can be mapped to "MYAPP.appspot.com/admin/index.jsp" automatically.

Is this something that can be configued on the domain management side or any special tool is needed?